# SQL where clause odd behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is a simple where clause from a single table. The problem is that I am not getting any results when I should. The AND is necessary as both conditions must be meet. The 2nd table shows that the condition should be met.

```
select *
from UserPermissions up
where up.PermissionId = 5 and up.PermissionId = 7

select *
from UserPermissions up
where up.UserId = '40376a15-8b4b-43c0-a174-67f935ec7e8e'
```

Here are the results. The first query returns no results, but Select 2 shows results from specific user. Rows 2 and 3 show that the PermissionId should match up.

[image]

There looks to be some misunderstandings on what I'm asking. Most likely how it was worded. What I'm expecting is to get a single UserID for each user who has *both* PermissionID of 5 (in one row) and 7 (in another row).

Comment: Your first query you have `PermissionId` with 2 values at the same time, that is not possible.

Comment: `up.PermissionId` can NEVER be `5` and `7` at the same time in ONE SINGLE ROW!!! 1NF violated!

Comment: Who just went down and marked every single answer incorrect?  That's not cool at all.

Comment: @durbnpoisn Why is not cool downvoting incorrect answers?

Comment: You need to describe exactly what result you expect. You have a handful of people who might be solving the problem, but WHO KNOWS?

Comment: Your update doesn't clarify anything. Do you want one row per user (just the userID of any user who has both permissions), two rows per user (the userID and the permissionID, not sure what value that has) or all rows per user (again, questionable value)?

Comment: @VDohnal he wants users that have ***BOTH 5 AND 7*** - OR doesn't do that.

Comment: @Aaron you are reading too much into it ;). I was just asking the userID of any user who has both permissions.

Comment: @VDohnal Oh boy. Please read the requirement again. They want to return users who have both permissionID 5 (on ***ONE*** row), and permissionID 7 (on ***ANOTHER*** row). I don't know how so many people can get this basic part of the requirement so wrong.

Comment: @VDohnal in OP's set up on user can have many permissions in this table. He want's all users who have permissions 5 and 7. This would be easy as pie if his database was any sort of relational. However since it blows he will probably have to join the table to itself.

Comment: @ClumsyHamster Then the answer by Daniel is what you want?

Comment: @ClumsyHamster Uh, that's what I was describing. And wasting a whole lot of energy doing. Perhaps you aren't reading enough into it? Can you answer my question above please, and incorporate that information into the question? It's pretty simple: ***SHOW US THE EXACT RESULT SET YOU EXPECT.***

Comment: @AaronBertrand relax. You are taking something simple way to personal or trying to make it personal. bluefeet and BhupeshC were right on and it makes sense but I can't think of a solution and VDohnal is trying to help. What you so angry about?

Comment: The amount of time and effort you could have saved by writing a clear question in the first place. Try to be considerate of all the people's time you are wasting, trying to help you, making incorrect guesses about your requirements because you can't be bothered to be clear. I'm not taking anything personal, I just think it's disrespectful to let all these people fail at answering your question correctly because you don't want to clarify what you are actually asking.

Comment: No one is angry. But you are sure trying hard to make us.

Comment: You could've avoided the whole misunderstanding on the wording of your question if you had posted a sample of the desired result. No one likes a word problem

Comment: @ypercube I see now. When I tested it, it only showed a single permissionId and not both as I was thinking it would. But the users I was expecting came through.

Comment: This is why people stop coming here to help.

Comment: @ypercube:  ^This is why.  The first 5 answers that came in were correct, based on the OP.  People lost a lot of reputation because the question was not clear from the beginning.  I know that most of them have been deleted now.  But the principle still stands.

Comment: @durbnpoisn The question was not clear indeed. It still isn't (and that's why it's in -6). The first 5 answers were not correct, only one of them, the rest 4 which are now deleted were an attempt to answer the unclear question. I assure you that there are several people that guessed what was asked but were not sure only for the exact output wanted. And the reputation is gained back when a downvoted answer is deleted.

Comment: @durbnpoisn if you don't have a solid idea for what the OP wants then don't answer the question. Problem solved.

Comment: For me it was a lesson, that after 2 bottles of wine and 2 hours of sleep I should not discuss programming questions...

Comment: Guys, all of us are here to try and help.  People shouldn't be punished when they give what they expect to be a correct answer.  That should only happen when someone actually answers incorrectly.

Comment: @durbnpoisn "People lost a lot of reputation", really?, *a lot*?

Comment: Collectively, yes.  Not everyone has 31k to play with.  :)

Comment: @durbnpoisn What does your current rep have to do with it? If you want to make wild guesses at answers before you fully understand the requirements, then you risk producing an incorrect answer that may get down-voted by your peers. That's a whole ***TWO*** imaginary Internet points for every down-vote. From there you have many choices. If you *delete* the wrong answer, you get all that rep back, just like that. If you *correct* the wrong answer, you stand to make a lot more back in up-votes, even if the original down-voters are long gone. If you just leave it as is, well.. *shrug*

Comment: @durbnpoisn Unlike this imaginary reputation that has been lost and then re-gained, what *can't* be recovered is the time and effort wasted by everyone involved with this question to (a) pull teeth to get the right requirements from the OP and (b) correct and re-correct and try to explain, to several of these people who jumped to the wrong conclusion about the nature of the problem, exactly how they got it wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with your original query is you are asking to return results where the `PermissionId` is equal to two values at the same time - meaning the same row - this is impossible.

However you can get return the `UserID` that has both `PermissionId =5` **AND** `PermissionId =7` by using a `GROUP BY` with a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT userId
FROM UserPermissions up
WHERE PermissionId IN (5, 7)
GROUP BY userId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PermissionId) = 2
```

Comment: I like your option better.

Comment: It does definitely scale better (both in code and performance) when you are checking for someone with 3, or 7, or 15 permissions...

Comment: @blufeet this was good as well. I'll try to remember the same row problem you initially mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

Alright OP does this do anything for you?

```
select
    a.UserId
from UserPermissions as a
inner join userpermissions as b
    on a.userID = b.userID
    and a.permissionID = 5
    and b.permissionID = 7
```

Comment: Thanks Zane. This looked to have solved it. Appreciate your help. Zane gave bluefeet credit as he posted a bit before you. Thx.

Answer (score 3):

This or a self join will give you the correct result, users that have both 5 AND 7 in the permissions column.

```
select up.UserID
from UserPermissions up
where up.PermissionId = 5 
and up.UserID in (Select userID 
                FROM UserPermissions up1 
                where up1.PermissionId = 7
               )
```

Comment: But this will only return the row where permissionId = 5. I don't think we understand the requirement enough yet to know what is actually expected.

Comment: True enough, with some clarification in the question... it does appear however that he is actually looking for just the qualified userID's as `select *` is giving back just those 2 columns.